# HIbernate - foreign key query failing

Tags: mysql, hibernate, db2

Please find my two tables

```
CREATE TABLE "DBS_P2P"."KW_PAYMENT_IMAGEE_TEST"(IMAGE_KEY INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (  START WITH +1 INCREMENT BY +1 MINVALUE +1 MAXVALUE +2147483647  NO CYCLE CACHE 20 NO ORDER),REQUEST_ID INTEGER,IMAGE_CONTENT CLOB(5120000),FOREIGN KEY(REQUEST_ID) REFERENCES KW_PAYMENT_LINK_MASTER_TEST(REQUEST_ID))



CREATE TABLE "DBS_P2P"."KW_PAYMENT_IMAGEE_TEST"(IMAGE_KEY INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (  START WITH +1 INCREMENT BY +1 MINVALUE +1 MAXVALUE +2147483647  NO CYCLE CACHE 20 NO ORDER),REQUEST_ID INTEGER,IMAGE_CONTENT CLOB(5120000),FOREIGN KEY(REQUEST_ID) REFERENCES KW_PAYMENT_LINK_MASTER_TEST(REQUEST_ID))


<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="xyz" table="KW_PAYMENT_LINK_MASTER_TEST" catalog="xyz">
    <id name="requestId" type="int">
        <column name="REQUEST_ID"/>
        <generator class="identity"  />  
    </id>

    <property name="referenceWalletId" type="string">
        <column name="REFERENCE_ID"/>
    </property>

</class>
```

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.kony.p2p.bo.KwPaymentImagetest" table="KW_PAYMENT_IMAGEE_TEST" catalog="DBS_P2P">

     <id name="imageKey" type="int">
        <column name="IMAGE_KEY"  />
        <generator class="identity" />  
    </id>

    <many-to-one name="KwPaymentLinkMastertest" class="com.kony.p2p.bo.KwPaymentLinkMastertest" fetch="select" lazy="false">
        <column name="REQUEST_ID" not-null="false"  />
    </many-to-one>

    <property name="imageContent" type="string">
        <column name="IMAGE_CONTENT" not-null="false" />
    </property>

</class>
<filter-def name="myFilter">
```

Im able to insert but not able to retrieve the result .

```
session.createCriteria(KwPaymentLinkMastertest.class).add(Restrictions.eq("requestId", Integer.parseInt(transactionReferenceNumber) )).uniqueResult();


   KwPaymentImagetest image = (KwPaymentImagetest) session.createCriteria(KwPaymentImagetest.class).add(Restrictions.eq("kwPaymentLinkMastertest", kwPaymentLinkMastertest)).uniqueResult();
```

Getting the following error

org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: kwPaymentLinkMastertest of: com.kony.p2p.bo.KwPaymentImagetest

Please help fix

Answer (score 2):

I think you have typing mistake here.

```
<many-to-one name="KwPaymentLinkMastertest" with K is upper case
while Restrictions.eq("kwPaymentLinkMastertest" with k is lower case.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya,
   You are right .

The problem was with small letter and capital letter , this helped to fix my problem.

Thanks.